# Netlogo: measuring time using distance and tick interval

Tags: netlogo

I have a model where I want to measure the time a turtle takes to travel from from one patch to another given the scale of the map, 'speed' or distance traveled (map scale is 1000m x 1000m per patch for reference), and a desired time that elapses in one tick (in seconds).

I am trying to count the total time it takes using a turtles-own variable called totaltime.

- Total time is determined by taking the total number of ticks minus extra ticks and then multiplying it by the time-interval (last line of code).
- Extra ticks are counted because the loop has to operate when the ship is moving directly to the center of the patch in the list. this is necessary so the patch can be removed from the list allowing the turtle to search for the next patch in the list and so on (in the ifelse statement).

The use of extra-ticks may be redundant and jumping to exact patch locations may certainly not be the best way to have turtles traverse through a list of patches. Unfortunately I am new to netlogo and don't have a great grasp on the concept of ticks and correct context (turtle, observer, etc). If anyone could help me it would GREATLY appreciated as I have been stuck trying to figure this out for way too long.

> ```
> > to move
> >           set speed 40
> >           set time-interval 1
> >           set ship-distance (time-interval / 3600) * speed 
> >           set extra-ticks 0
> >           tick
> >           ask ships with [length current-path != 0] 
> >               [       
> >                 go-to-next-patch-in-current-path 
> >               ]
> >         end
> >         
> >         to go-to-next-patch-in-current-path  
> >           face first current-path
> >           set total-ticks total-ticks + 1
> >           ifelse distance first current-path <= ship-distance
> >             [
> >               set extra-ticks (1 - (distance first current-path / ship-distance)) + extra-ticks
> >               print (distance first current-path / ship-distance)
> >               move-to first current-path
> >               set current-path remove-item 0 current-path
> >             ]
> >             [
> >               set normal-ticks normal-ticks + 1
> >               fd ship-distance
> >             ]
> >       
> >           set totaltime  (ticks - extra-ticks) * time-interval / 60   
> >         end
> ```